# Проблема создания Теневой копии тома по расписанию в Windows Server 2012R2

Tags: резервное-копирование, windows-server-2012

Друзья, работал ли кто-то с резервированием в Windows Server посредством создания теневых копий томов (VSS) ?

Первая копия делается нормально, но при повторной копии выскакивает ошибка `Теневые копии тома D: удалены из-за невозможности увеличения хранилища теневых копий.  Уменьшите загрузку ввода-вывода для системы или выберите другой том для  хранилища теневых копий, который не подлежит теневому копированию.` и все теневые копии удаляются.

Сидим уже сутки с этой проблемой и никак не можем побороть, решения с форума техподдержки мелкомягких не помогают.....

*Проблема на виртуальной машине, которая крутиться на HyperV. Подобных проблем на хосте и других ВМ нет.*

Answer (score 0):

Проблема оказалась во включенном компоненте "Затирание данных" Secret Net Studio